# Trying to get my playCount method to work in music player

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a playcount method for my musicplayer.

In my track method I have defined a field as playCount and then created a method that increments it. But I can't seem to have it called in my main class when a song is played.

```
public class Track
{
// The artist.
private String artist;
// The track's title.
private String title;
// Where the track is stored.
private String filename;

public int playCount;
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Track.
 * @param artist The track's artist.
 * @param title The track's title.
 * @param filename The track file. 
 */
public Track(String artist, String title, String filename)
{
    setDetails(artist, title, filename);
    playCount = 0;
}

public void resetCount(){
    playCount = 0;
}

public void incrementCount(){
    playCount++;
}
```

And here's my main class some code omitted.

```
public class MusicOrganizer
{
// An ArrayList for storing music tracks.
private ArrayList<Track> tracks;
// A player for the music tracks.
private MusicPlayer player;
// A reader that can read music files and load them as tracks.
private TrackReader reader;

/**
 * Create a MusicOrganizer
 */
public MusicOrganizer()
{
    tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    player = new MusicPlayer();
    reader = new TrackReader();
    readLibrary("audio");
    System.out.println("Music library loaded. " + getNumberOfTracks() + " tracks.");
    System.out.println();
}

/**
 * Add a track file to the collection.
 * @param filename The file name of the track to be added.
 */
public void addFile(String filename)
{
    tracks.add(new Track(filename));
}

/**
 * Add a track to the collection.
 * @param track The track to be added.
 */
public void addTrack(Track track)
{
    tracks.add(track);
}

/**
 * Play a track in the collection.
 * @param index The index of the track to be played.
 */
public void playTrack(int index)
{
    if(indexValid(index)) {
        Track.incrementCount(); //This is where my problem is. I just want to call the increment   method so that it adds one.
        stopPlaying();
        Track track = tracks.get(index);
        player.startPlaying(track.getFilename());
        System.out.println("Now playing: " + track.getArtist() + " - " + track.getTitle());
    }
}
```

what I get is an error "non static method incrementCount() cannot be referenced from a static context. I do not understand this and how I should fix it.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's a non static method, you need to call it on an instance. You need try calling that after `Track track = tracks.get(index);` and need to call like `track.incrementCount();`.

Comment: @Rp- That worked wonders! Could you explain why I need to call it after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this on the `track` instance, not the `Track` class.

```
public void playTrack(int index)
{
    if(indexValid(index)) {
        Track track = tracks.get(index);
        stopPlaying();
        player.startPlaying(track.getFilename());
        track.incrementCount();
        System.out.println("Now playing: " + track.getArtist() + " - " + track.getTitle());
    }
}
```